# java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException while writing the dataframe to MariaDB

Tags: apache-spark, jdbc, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, mariadb

I am able to make connection the mariaDB and read the data from table, however, the same connection is not working to write the data in MariaDB Table.

```
df.write.format("jdbc") \
.mode("append") \
.option("driver", "org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver") \
.option("url", "jdbc:mariadb://[host]:[port]/[db]") \
.option("user", "[user name]") \
.option("password", "[password]") \
.option("dbtable", "[table_name]").save()
```

I am getting the following error while performing the save operation

```
    Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o647.save.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 91 in stage 56.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 91.3 in stage 56.0 (TID 2319) ([SPARK host] executor 13): java.sql.BatchUpdateException: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: (conn=50615) Socket error
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.export.ExceptionFactory.createBatchUpdate(ExceptionFactory.java:213)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.client.impl.StandardClient.executePipeline(StandardClient.java:599)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeBatchPipeline(ClientPreparedStatement.java:186)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternalPreparedBatch(ClientPreparedStatement.java:117)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeBatch(ClientPreparedStatement.java:454)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.savePartition(JdbcUtils.scala:692)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.$anonfun$saveTable$1(JdbcUtils.scala:856)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.$anonfun$saveTable$1$adapted(JdbcUtils.scala:854)
```